# something different about NSURLSessionDelegate and NSURLSessionTaskDelegate in AFURLSessionManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

## pragma mark - NSURLSessionDelegate

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session 
didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
    __block NSURLCredential *credential = nil;

    if (self.sessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge) {
        disposition = self.sessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(session, challenge, &credential);
    } else {
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
            if ([self.securityPolicy evaluateServerTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust forDomain:challenge.protectionSpace.host]) {
                credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
                if (credential) {
                    disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
                } else {
                    disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
                }
            } else {
                disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeRejectProtectionSpace;
            }
        } else {
            disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
        }
    }

    if (completionHandler) {
        completionHandler(disposition, credential);
    }
}
```

## pragma mark - NSURLSessionTaskDelegate

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
    __block NSURLCredential *credential = nil;

    if (self.taskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge) {
        disposition = self.taskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(session, task, challenge, &credential);
    } else {
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
            if ([self.securityPolicy evaluateServerTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust forDomain:challenge.protectionSpace.host]) {
                disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
                credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
            } else {
                disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeRejectProtectionSpace;
            }
        } else {
            disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
        }
    }

    if (completionHandler) {
        completionHandler(disposition, credential);
    }
}
```

****in *URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler*,when after create the *credential* will check if the credential is nil or not,then set the *disposition* value,but in  *URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler*,after create the *credential*,it doesn't check,it set the *disposition* value directly?****